# Laravel queue event not serializing models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-echo

Not sure if i did something wrong, but when attempting do broadcast an event, the `SerializesModels` only serializes the first model I throw at it.

```
class WorkerQueueEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
  use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

  protected $user;
  public $queue;
  public function __construct(User $user,QueueJob $queue)
  {
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->queue = $queue;
  }
  public function broadcastOn()
  {    
    return new PrivateChannel('Queues/' . $this->user->id);
  }
}
```

This results in the queue never being processed.
If i do an `dd($queue);` or `dd($user);` in the constructer, it does log both of them, but it never reaches broadcastOn();

I did got it to work, passing QueueJob id and fetching it on the broadcast function, just asking if i was doing something wrong or if this is in fact an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue here is your `public $queue` property.

[The documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting#broadcast-queue) states that you can specify an event queue by defining the `$broadcastQueue` property. However, it doesn't mention that it also checks for the `$queue` property if `$broadcastQueue` is not defined.

Since you have defined a `$queue` property, it will attempt to push your event onto the queue named by the `__toString()` value of your `QueueJob` model instance, which I'm assuming doesn't exist and why your job is never sent to a queue.

If you rename your property to something like `$queueJob`, then I believe it should work for you.

Comment: That does seem to make sense, i'll try it out.

Comment: Should've tried to see defined variables or look more deeply into what was being done by the framework before doing a silly workaround. Thanks for the answer / clarifying me.

Answer (score 0):

for running queues you have to run `php artisan queue:work`

for this also make sure that driver is `database` you can set it your `.env` file.

Hope this helps

Comment: I got the queues working with redis, The only problem there, is that if i pass a two elequent model instead of just one, it never reaches the broadcast function. there are more queues working and even this one, but i just can't pass more than one model to it, need to pass id's and fetch the model in the broadcast function

Comment: for this queue to work, i pass an ID as the second parameter, and fetch it into the public prop `$queue` before returning it to the private channel so Echo returns me that model