# Notification don't work on queue but work as Direct

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, queue, laravel-5.5

i have a issue with notifications on laravel, if i send a notification directly without a queue this work as well

this notifiction needs send a email and save in database

i use this to call notify as exemple

```
$user = \App\User::find(1);
    $candidato = \App\CandidatoVaga::where('id_user','=','1')->first();
    $user->notify(new \App\Notifications\ConviteVagaCandidato($candidato));
```

And this is \App\Notifications\ConviteVagaCandidato

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
class ConviteVagaCandidato extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
use Queueable;
protected $CandidatoVaga;
/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(\App\CandidatoVaga $CandidatoVaga)
{
    $this->CandidatoVaga = $CandidatoVaga;
}
/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['database','mail'];
}

/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
    ->greeting('Olá, '.$this->CandidatoVaga->user->DadosPessoais->nome)
    ->subject('Convite')
    ->markdown('email.convite_selecao');
}
/**
 * Get the array representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
return [
        'id_vaga' => $this->CandidatoVaga->id_vaga,
        'id_user' => $this->CandidatoVaga->id_user,
        'mensagem' => 'Você foi pré selecionado para a vaga',
        'tipo' => 'Nova Vaga',
    ];
}
}
```

This return a sql error SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERRO
but without `implements ShouldQueue` works as well

Comment: What is the sql error?

Comment: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERRO: delimited identifier has zero size in or near """"
LINE 1: ... * from "candidatos_vaga" where "candidatos_vaga"."" is null...
^ (SQL: select * from "candidatos_vaga" where "candidatos_vaga"."" is null limit 1)

Comment: Try to log `$this->CandidatoVaga` and check it in laravel.log

Comment: I think this is the problem, i remove all $this->CandidatoVaga and work, but what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps the model isn't loading the model correctly, had troubles with serialize problems before.

Comment: if i do dd($CandidatoVaga); on __construct this return the correctly data

Comment: Had a problem with that before, still unanswered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48864247/laravel-queue-event-not-serializing-models

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the differences between the `sync` queue driver and a real queue driver is how the queued job handles stored Models.

Since the `sync` queue driver is processing the jobs directly in the same process, there is no extra work being done. If you build your `Notification` with a `Model`, it uses that exact model instance.

However, when using a real queue, Laravel has to serialize the data stored on the notification for the queue worker to handle it. Because models cannot be serialized easily, what it actually does is just store the model key on the notification, and then when the queue worker processes that job, it re-retrieves that model from the database using the stored key.

Based on the query you mentioned in the comments, it looks to me like your `\App\CandidatoVaga` model does not have a primary key (`$primaryKey` is empty). Because of this, there is no primary key field to query (`"candidatos_vaga".""`), and there is no primary key value stored (`is null`).

I see you've already come up with a solution for yourself. If, however, you still wanted to attempt to just use the model, you can try this:

1. Override the `getQueueableId()` method on your model. By default, this returns the primary key field. But, since you don't have one defined, you would need to override this method to provide some unique data that can be used to find your record again.
2. Override the `newQueryForRestoration()` method on your model. By default, this builds a query using the primary key field. But, since you don't have one defined, you would need to override this method to generate a query using the data generated by the `getQueueableId()` method.

NB: this is untested. I have never done this; this is just what I see looking through the source code.

Comment: in this modal i can use a composte primary key, if i set on model ill solve this problem?

Comment: @GuilhermeFreire No, Laravel's eloquent doesn't support composite primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it in a palliative way

```
public $id_vaga;
public $id_user;
public $nome;
public $titulo_vaga;
/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($CandidatoVaga)
{

    $this->id_vaga = $CandidatoVaga->id_vaga;
    $this->id_user = $CandidatoVaga->id_user;
    $this->nome = $CandidatoVaga->user->DadosPessoais->nome;
    $this->titulo_vaga = $CandidatoVaga->vaga->titulo_vaga;
}
```